# Extra interline glue between \vbox'es?

Tags: line-spacing, plain-tex

In the following example I use `\strut`'s in both lines, but nevertheless there is gap between the rules. Why there is this gap between two rules?

Example 1:

```
\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\vbox{\hrule Y\strut\hrule}
\bye
```

[image]

If we add `\nointerlineskip` or remove `\vbox` from only *one* `X` or `Y`, then the gap disappears. How can this be explained?

Example 2:

```
\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\nointerlineskip
\vbox{\hrule Y\strut\hrule}
\bye
```

[image]

Example 3:

```
X\strut\hrule
\vbox{\hrule Y\strut\hrule}
\bye
```

[image]

Example 4:

```
\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\hrule Y\strut\hrule
\bye
```

[image]

Also, if we remove the last `\hrule` from Example 1, the gap becomes bigger. Why?

Example 5:

```
\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\vbox{\hrule Y\strut}
\bye
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In Example 1, `\glue(\lineskip) 1.0` gets inserted between the two vboxes.  If you call `\nointerlineskip` explicitly as in Example 2, that glue is obviously missing.  Something similar holds for Example 3 and 4, where either an hbox is followed by a vbox or vice versa, which also suppresses the interlineskip (why? help me @egreg).  In Example 5 we have the same situation as in Example 1, but because the height of the second vbox is smaller than in Example 1, a larger glue is inserted, namely `\glue(\baselineskip) 3.1`.  I don't know how TeX comes up with this value.

Answer (score 4):

Look for `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit` in the TeXbook: there is no *extra* glue, because the rules tell TeX to do like this.

If you look at the ruled table examples in the TeXbook, you will notice that `\strut` is used, but also `\offinterlineskip` is issued in order to kill all interline glue insertion.

The rules are that TeX doesn't add interline glue (however determined with `\baselineskip` or `\lineskip`) before and after a rule, but your case is different, because the rule is buried in a box. Thus the computation for the interline glue between the two boxes is done purely by looking at their heights and depths.

You can try seeing this is the effect by setting `\lineskip` to 20pt, for instance.

Recall that the depth of a `\vbox` is determined by the *last* item in the vertical list and everything else is added to the height.

Thus the first `\vbox` has depth zero, whereas the height of the second box is determined by the fact that the last item is another rule, so the height comes to be 12.8pt which exceeds `\baselineskip-\lineskiplimit` and so `\lineskip` enters in the scene. Why 12.8? The first rule is 0.4pt high, the horizontal box contains a strut, so its height plus depth is 12pt and then there's another rule 0.4pt high; no depth for the last rule, so the depth of the `\vbox` is zero.

```
..\vbox(12.79999+0.0)x469.75499
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\hbox(8.5+3.5)x469.75499, glue set 442.25497fil []
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
```

Of course, adding `\nointerlineskip` fixes the problem or issuing `\offinterlineskip` that kills the interline glue computations by telling TeX that `\lineskiplimit` is `\maxdimen`, so two lines will never be too near to each other and the baselineskip is set to -1000pt.

The example with the `\vbox` followed by the `\hrule` at the top level is obvious: TeX doesn't add interline glue before and after rules.

Comment: "...you will notice that \strut is used, but also \offinterlineskip is issued..." - I wonder if `\strut` is so fundamental that we cannot do without it in these situations. Is there any alternative (perhaps by using engine-specific or Lua features) to get the same output?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko If you remove the interline glue and don't issue `\strut` for each line, TeX has no way other than stacking lines above each other. In XeTeX there is an option for making all characters having the same bounding box.

Comment: This `\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=0` feature seems not to work for LM-fonts. Was it introduced only for OpenType fonts?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko It works only for OpenType or TrueType fonts, like several other features of XeTeX.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example

```
\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\vbox{\hrule Y\strut\hrule}

\setbox0\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\the\ht0, \the\dp0

\setbox0\vbox{\hrule Y\strut\hrule}
\the\ht0, \the\dp0

\the\baselineskip
\nopagenumbers    
\bye
```

the added vertical glue is `\lineskip` glue.

> [image: Blockquote]

The second box (also the first but that is not relevant here, only location of its reference point matters) has a height exceeding `\baselineskip`, hence an attempt to position its reference point `\baselineskip` below the reference point of the first box results in a negative distance from the bottom of box 1 to top of box 2. As `Plain` has `\lineskiplimit` set at `0pt`, the rules (see `TeX by Topic`, `15.1 Interline glue`) cause `TeX` to insert the `\lineskip` glue.

As per Example 5, here is what

```
\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\vbox{\hrule Y\strut}

\setbox0\vbox{X\strut\hrule}
\the\ht0, \the\dp0

\setbox0\vbox{\hrule Y\strut}
\the\ht0, \the\dp0

\the\baselineskip

\nopagenumbers
\bye
```

produces:

> [image: Blockquote]

It shows where the reference point of the `Y` box is located, hence (so called) baselineskip glue (not the same as `\baselineskip` itself) is inserted to get the two reference points the `\baselineskip` apart: precisely `12pt-8.9pt=3.1pt`

You can also diagnose further with `\tracingoutput1` added to the source:

```
..\glue(\baselineskip) 3.1
```